# some questions ablout startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, start-activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
intent.setType("image/*"); 
startActivityForResult(intent, TServiceInfo.ACTIVITY_PICSELECTED);
```

Like some code above, Activity will Jump into system gallery.
 But will startActivity run TServiceInfo.class or not?

`TServiceInfo.ACTIVITY_PICSELECTED` equals 4, can I write to this `startActivityForResult(intent, 4);` What's the difference between them?

(TServiceInfo.class is a connect-class between client and server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Make sure you use the same as `requestCode` in `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 1):

`TServiceInfo.ACTIVITY_PICSELECTED` is useful when you have multiple things to do in **onActivityResult** method !

Which also depends on many things like if u want that videos should be viewed in gallery / or for audio then you can set 2 more integer variables like ACTIVITY_VIDEO_SELECTED,ACTIVITY_AUDIO_SELECTED !

You can have many instances of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
intent.setType("video/*"); 
startActivityResult(intent, TServiceInfo.ACTIVITY_VIDEO_SELECTED);
```

Or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
intent.setType("audio/*"); 
startActivityResult(intent, TServiceInfo.ACTIVITY_AUDIO_SELECTED);
```

But You can have only **one** instance of **onActivityResult** ! So in this method you can use the values to predict that from which instance it has been called like :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == TServiceInfo.ACTIVITY_PICSELECTED && resultCode == RESULT_OK &&null != data)
      {

                // do something here
      }
      if (requestCode == TServiceInfo.ACTIVITY_VIDEO_SELECTED && resultCode == RESULT_OK &&null != data)
      {
                 // do something here

      }
      if (requestCode == TServiceInfo.ACTIVITY_AUDIO_SELECTED && resultCode == RESULT_OK &&null != data)
      {
                 // do something here

      }
}
```

So by maintaining the values of these variables(`ACTIVITY_PICSELECTED`,`ACTIVITY_VIDEO_SELECTED`,`ACTIVITY_AUDIO_SELECTED`) You can predict which code should be executed !

Comment: there are some static methods which are used to connect to server and get results from server in TServerInfo.class. I'd like to know whether will it(startActivityResult(intent, TServiceInfo.ACTIVITY_PICSELECTED);) run these methods. Because I can not find that codes which call these methods.

Comment: If it is a background thread extending Async Task then it is inflated using `new TServerInfo().execute("");`